# Getting error message for array_push method in php

Tags: php, array-push

Here is the code for my class:

```
<?php
include ('Special.php');

class SpecialContainer
{
    private $dataArray;

    public function _construct()
    {
       $this->dataArray = array();
        echo"Created new Location instance<br/>";
    }

    public function addSpecialItem($Special_Item)
    {
        array_push($this->dataArray, $Special_Item);
    }

}
?>
```

Its throwing an error at the following line in another php file:

```
$SpecialContainerObj->addSpecialItem($SpecialObj);
```

The error is this:

```
Warning: array_push() [function.array-push]: First argument should be an array in /home/**********s/SpecialContainer.php on line 16
```

..

Im confused, could someone clarify please how I can resolve this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public function _construct()
```

There is a missing underscore. You should also notice, that your message is never `echo`d

```
public function __construct()
```

However, you should define something like this directly within the class declaration

```
class Foo {
  private $dataArray = array();

  // Other code
}
```

Comment: Thanks that seemed to solve the problem. But my question is How come you say initialize the variable outside the constructor. Isn't it good practice to do so in the constructor?

Comment: In short: This _is_ the initialization. Doing so in the constructor is just unnecessary